# How do SQL history tables work when there are foreign keys at play?

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say I have 2 tables:

**User:**

```
ID: PK, AI
username: varchar
pwd: varchar
addressID: FK references address.ID
```

**Address:**

```
ID: PK, AI
street varchar,
houseNr varchar,
postal varchar,
```

How would the history tables look like since we obviously have foreign keys.
The requirement: we must be able to see all the addresses that were ever linked to a user.

The way I see it is that if we update user, a new entry goes into the user_history table.
That entry must point to an address, we can't point to the address in the address table since if that would change we would have the new data instead of the one at this point of time.

So how I see it on update of address we must also duplicate the address to the address_history table so our user can reference that foreign key to always remain historized.

How would it happen in practice?

Comment: The `address_history` table should have all the same columns as `address`, plus a date column that shows when it was replaced.

Comment: Agreed, but that was not my question, I was looking more for an answer on how the foreign keys would work

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again!

Answer (score 0):

In every case I have seen implemented in a real-world database, the reference is the other way around:

User:

```
ID: PK, AI
username: varchar
pwd: varchar
```

Address:

```
ID: PK, AI
userid: reference to User
street varchar
houseNr varchar
postal varchar
is_current bool
```

So addresses may come and go, but all addresses used by a given user reference that user's id. Old addresses that are no longer used by that user only need to set `is_current=false`, but the record still exists permanently.

It also still works if old address records are moved to an `Address_history` table; the foreign key in the address record still points to the former owner by its user id.

Another advantage for switching the reference the other way is that a given user may have multiple addresses that are current.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. This helps! However I am still curious as to how history tables work with foreign keys in general, could you please provide me some insight on this?

Comment: So-called history tables are just like any other table. All values in the foreign key column must exist in the primary key of the table it references.

Comment: Yes sorry that wasn't what I meant with my question. I meant how do I point to the data at the time of that history. Obviously we don't want to reference the non history table, because then it wouldn't stay historized. So what do we do on update of address we insert both address and user into their respective history tables and link them or how would that work?

Comment: I wouldn't define any foreign key constraint in the history tables, because they won't reference a single row. Either the respective user record might be deleted (e.g. if you are legally required to for GDPR or something), or if you try to reference the user history table, there could be multiple rows with the same user id. A foreign key should reference a _single_ row.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your above implementation in which we put the foreign key inside the address table. Means that we can't update the addres but must insert a new one right?

Comment: You can update the non-history table, but I assume you would want the history table to have a new row for each update. So the history is basically insert-only.

Answer (score 0):

The `Address_History` table should have a `User_ID` foreign key referencing `User.ID`.

```
ID: PK, AI
User_ID: FK references User.ID
street varchar,
houseNr varchar,
postal varchar,
date_replaced datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp
```

When you replace a user's address, you copy `street`, `houseNr`, and `postal` to the new `Address_History` row, and set its `User_ID` column to the user's ID.

`User_history` also has a FK to `User.ID`.

```
ID: PK, AI
username: varchar
pwd: varchar
addressID: FK references address.ID
orig_userID: FK references User.ID
date_updated: datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp
```

Comment: In your example the address_history table is pointing to the current User_ID, so lets say a day later we change the username, the address will be pointed to the row with the new user ID. Which is not valid as per my requirement. It needs to point to the data that was there at the time of the address update.

Comment: user history should be separate from address history.

Comment: I've added the `User_History` table. But I see what you mean about the FK problem. The saved copy of `addressID` will point to an old address. Probably the other answer's solution is better.